# Update a bokeh plot using ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, bokeh

I have a similar question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26536187/1534017). I have a website containing several elements, such as a table and a bokeh plot which I want to update once the user gives a certain input. While I can accomplish this for the table, I don't know how to update the bokeh plot.

In the example below, I use a minimal example where the user input determines the dimensions of a table. So an output looks like this:

[image]

The update of the table works great and as expected, however, I struggle to update the plot accordingly. I can initialize it easily using (entire code can be found at the end of this post):

```
@app.route('/')
def index():

    # just an initial figure
    p = figure(plot_width=150, plot_height=100)

    p.line([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
    # save(p, 'testing.html')

    script_bok, div_bok = components(p)
    return render_template('index.html', div_bok=div_bok, script_bok=script_bok)
```

and can then fetch the user's choice by

```
@app.route('/_get_table')
def get_table():

    nrow = request.args.get('nrow', type=int)
    ncol = request.args.get('ncol', type=int)

    # the table we want to display
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(nrow, ncol)))

    # the updated/new plot
    p = figure(plot_width=150, plot_height=100)

    p.line(list(range(nrow)), list(range(nrow)))
    # save(p, 'testing.html')

    script_bok, div_bok = components(p)

    # how would I pass those now?

    return jsonify(my_table=json.loads(df.to_json(orient="split"))["data"],
                   columns=[{"title": str(col)} for col in json.loads(df.to_json(orient="split"))["columns"]],
                   div_bok=div_bok,
                   script_bok=script_bok)
```

The question is: **How do I now feed the new components to `index.html` so that the plot is updated along with the table but all the other elements on the page are untouched?**

There are now two answers that solve the issue. I still decided to use a bounty to find even better answers. Things that could be improved:

1) Right now, the plot is always drawn from scratch, ideally, only the data would be updated.

2) Is there a way to avoid the additional template (below it is called `update_content.html`)?

If no additional answer shows up, I am more than happy to provide the points to @Anthonydouc for [his nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50312041/1534017).

This is my entire code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, save
from bokeh.embed import components

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():

    # just an initial figure
    p = figure(plot_width=150, plot_height=100)

    p.line([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
    # save(p, 'testing.html')

    script_bok, div_bok = components(p)
    return render_template('index.html', div_bok=div_bok, script_bok=script_bok)


@app.route('/_get_table')
def get_table():

    nrow = request.args.get('nrow', type=int)
    ncol = request.args.get('ncol', type=int)

    # the table we want to display
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(nrow, ncol)))

    # the updated/new plot
    p = figure(plot_width=150, plot_height=100)

    p.line(list(range(nrow)), list(range(nrow)))
    # save(p, 'testing.html')

    script_bok, div_bok = components(p)

    # how would I pass those now?

    return jsonify(my_table=json.loads(df.to_json(orient="split"))["data"],
                   columns=[{"title": str(col)} for col in json.loads(df.to_json(orient="split"))["columns"]],
                   div_bok=div_bok,
                   script_bok=script_bok)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

and my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.15.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.15.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
          <h3 class="text-muted">some stuff</h3>
        </div>

        <hr class="mb-4">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
      <form id="input_data_form" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="nrow">rows</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nrow" min="0" step="1" placeholder="" value="2" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              please provide an integer
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="ncol">columns</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ncol" min="0" step="1" placeholder="" value="2" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              please provide an integer
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row text-center">
          <div class="col-12">
              <button id="calculate" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate!</button>
          </div>
       </div>
      </form>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">

          <div class="header">
            <h5 class="text-muted">Plot results</h5>
          </div>
          {{div_bok|safe}}
          {{script_bok|safe}}
        </div>
     </div>

      <hr class="mb-4">

      <table id="a_nice_table" class="table table-striped"></table>

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.15.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.15.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = null;
        $('#input_data_form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($('#input_data_form')[0].checkValidity() === false) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                if (table !== null) {
                    table.destroy();
                    table = null;
                    $("#a_nice_table").empty();
                  }
            } else {
                $.getJSON('/_get_table', {
                    nrow: $("#nrow").val(),
                    ncol: $("#ncol").val()

                  }, function(data) {

                  //document.body.append($(data.script_bok)[0]);

                  //$("#bokeh_plot").html(data.div_bok);

                  if (table !== null) {
                    table.destroy();
                    table = null;
                    $("#a_nice_table").empty();
                  }
                  table = $("#a_nice_table").DataTable({
                    data: data.my_table,
                    columns: data.columns

                  });
                });
            return false;
            }
            $('#input_data_form').addClass('was-validated');
        });

      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have deleted the table from your example, and just focused on updating the bokeh plot. Important to note in this example the plot is being re-created each time you press calculate.

There are now three files - server code (app.py), base template (index.html) and a template to render only bokeh plot (update_content.html). Both the templates need to be in the templates folder as usual.

The '_get_table' endpoint now returns rendered html containing the bokeh plot. Clicking the calculate button will trigger a callback, which in turn submits a post request to this endpoint. 
app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, save
from bokeh.embed import components

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():

    # just an initial figure
    p = figure(plot_width=150, plot_height=100)

    p.line([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
    # save(p, 'testing.html')

    script_bok, div_bok = components(p)
    return render_template('index.html', div_bok=div_bok, script_bok=script_bok)


@app.route('/_get_table', methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_table():

    # extract nrow, ncol via ajax post - contained in request.form
    nrow = request.form.get('nrow', type=int)
    ncol = request.form.get('ncol', type=int)

    # the updated/new plot
    p = figure(plot_width=150, plot_height=100)

    p.line(list(range(nrow)), list(range(nrow)))

    script_bok, div_bok = components(p)

    #return rendered html to the browser

    return render_template('update_content.html', div_bok=div_bok, script_bok=script_bok)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.15.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.15.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
          <h3 class="text-muted">some stuff</h3>
        </div>

        <hr class="mb-4">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
      <form id="input_data_form" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="nrow">rows</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nrow" min="0" step="1" placeholder="" value="2" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              please provide an integer
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="ncol">columns</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ncol" min="0" step="1" placeholder="" value="2" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              please provide an integer
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row text-center">
          <div class="col-12">
              <button id="calculate" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate!</button>
          </div>
       </div>
      </form>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="header">
            <h5 class="text-muted">Plot results</h5>
          </div>
          <div id="plot-content">
            {{div_bok|safe}}
            {{script_bok|safe}}
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.15.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.15.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#calculate').on('click', function(e){
          // prevent page being reset, we are going to update only
          // one part of the page.
          e.preventDefault()
          $.ajax({
            url:'./_get_table',
            type:'post',
            data:{'nrow':$("#nrow").val(),
                  'ncol':$("#ncol").val()},
            success : function(data){
              // server returns rendered "update_content.html"
              // which is just pure html, use this to replace the existing
              // html within the "plot content" div
              $('#plot-content').html(data)
            }
          })
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

update_content.html

```
{{div_bok|safe}}
{{script_bok|safe}}
```

Comment: Great, that works as advertised (upvoted). Question then still remains how to also update the table at the same time. Can one maybe return the `render_template` within a `jsonify`? Will try that...

Answer (score 3):

[@Anthonydouc's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50312041/1534017) got me on the right track, so all the credit should go to him; this is just an extension on how one can also update the table at the same time.

The key is to create an additional file, here `update_content.html` that will contain the required HTML for the plot which should be updated everytime the user provides some input. It contains only:

```
{{div_bok|safe}}
{{script_bok|safe}}
```

Given this, one can then use `render_template` to produce the HTML string that  represents the figure and passes it also via `jsonify`. The updated flask script therefore looks as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, save
from bokeh.embed import components

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/_get_table')
def get_table():

    nrow = request.args.get('nrow', type=int)
    ncol = request.args.get('ncol', type=int)

    # the table we want to display
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(nrow, ncol)))

    # the updated/new plot
    p = figure(plot_width=150, plot_height=100)

    p.line(list(range(nrow + 1)), list(range(nrow + 1)))
    # save(p, 'testing.html')

    script_bok, div_bok = components(p)

    # pass the div and script to render_template    
    return jsonify(my_table=json.loads(df.to_json(orient="split"))["data"],
                   columns=[{"title": str(col)} for col in json.loads(df.to_json(orient="split"))["columns"]],
                   html_plot=render_template('update_content.html', div_bok=div_bok, script_bok=script_bok))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

and the `index.html` file looks like this (make sure to use the correct `bokeh` version, here it is `0.12.15`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.15.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.15.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
          <h3 class="text-muted">some stuff</h3>
        </div>

        <hr class="mb-4">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
      <form id="input_data_form" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="nrow">rows</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nrow" min="0" step="1" placeholder="" value="2" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              please provide an integer
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="ncol">columns</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ncol" min="0" step="1" placeholder="" value="2" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              please provide an integer
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row text-center">
          <div class="col-12">
              <button id="calculate" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate!</button>
          </div>
       </div>
      </form>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">

          <div class="header">
            <h5 class="text-muted">Plot results</h5>
          </div>
          <div id="plot_content">

          </div>
        </div>
     </div>

      <hr class="mb-4">

      <table id="a_nice_table" class="table table-striped"></table>

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.15.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.15.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = null;
        $('#input_data_form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($('#input_data_form')[0].checkValidity() === false) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                if (table !== null) {
                    table.destroy();
                    table = null;
                    $("#a_nice_table").empty();
                  }
            } else {
                $.getJSON('/_get_table', {
                    nrow: $("#nrow").val(),
                    ncol: $("#ncol").val()

                  }, function(data) {

                  $('#plot_content').html(data.html_plot);

                  if (table !== null) {
                    table.destroy();
                    table = null;
                    $("#a_nice_table").empty();
                  }
                  table = $("#a_nice_table").DataTable({
                    data: data.my_table,
                    columns: data.columns

                  });
                });
            return false;
            }
            $('#input_data_form').addClass('was-validated');
        });

      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

There might be better options where the plot is really just updated instead of redrawn completely as in this solution, but that gets the job done for now.